# SQL code to add/update db column with array of user ID's

Tags: mysql, ajax, wordpress

I created a custom database in WP where I wish to create list of user's followers and following (based on ID's)

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'addon_users';

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
            username bigint(20) NOT NULL,
            following bigint(20) NOT NULL,
            followers bigint(20) NOT NULL,          
            PRIMARY KEY  (id),
            UNIQUE KEY id (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
```

My AJAX call:

```
public function addon_ajax_follow_me() {

            check_ajax_referer( 'km-ajax-create-nonce', 'security' );   

            $current_user   = get_current_user_id();
            $target_user    = isset( $_POST['data-follow-user'] ) ? $_POST['data-follow-user'] : false;

            if( ! empty( $_POST['data-follow-user'] ) ) {           
                $this->cgc_follow_user( $current_user, $target_user );
            }       

            wp_die();   

    }
```

Follow User function:

```
public function cgc_follow_user( $current_user = 0, $user_to_follow = 0  ) {

            ...

            $args = array(
                'user_id'   => $current_user,
                'following' => $user_to_follow
            );

            $this->add_follower( $args );
        }
```

This function is for updating the database and where I need help with.

```
public function add_follower( $args = array() ) {

            global $wpdb;

            $defaults = array(
                'user_id'       => '',
                'following'     => ''
            );

            $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

            $add = $wpdb->query(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "INSERT INTO {$this->table} SET
                        `user_id`       = '%d',
                        `following`     = '%d'
                    ;",
                    absint( $args['user_id'] ),
                    absint( $args['following'] )
                )
            );

            if ( $add )
                return $wpdb->insert_id;

            return false;
        }
```

This creates a new entry in database everytime a users follows another user. But I wish to build an array of user ID's instead. Something like this:

```
umeta_id   user_id   username    following      followers
    1         1       Yoonah     5,12,58,66      45, ...       
    2         5     Elisabeth     2,8,66         1,45, ...
    3         8        Max        45,9,99         5, ...
    4        45        Ace        1,5,87          8, ...
```

The thing I stumble upon is using the proper SQL code for adding arrays of IDs.

Plus, when 'Yoonah' (1) follows Elisabeth (5), the `followers` column for Elisabeth (5) should be updated with 'Yoonah' (1) as well.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand very well your question, I hope this is what you are talking about.

UPDATE:
I tested this code an it is working, the only issue is that I put a mandatory "username" if the user_id does not exists to create it, but I think because you are using a current user logged in in WordPress, it should work with not problem like it worked for me.

```
 Class TestThis {
    var $table = 'users';

    function __construct() {
        add_action( "wp_ajax_add_follower", array( $this, "add_follower" ) );
    }

    function add_follower() {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $args = array(
            'user_id'   => $current_user->ID,
            'follow_to' => $_POST['user_to_follow']
        );

        $response = $this->add_following( $args );
        if ( ! empty( $response ) && $response !== FALSE ) {
            $args = array(
                'user_id'   => $_POST['user_to_follow'],
                'followed_by' => $current_user->ID
            );

            $this->add_followed_by( $args );
        }

        wp_die();
    }

    function add_following ( $args = array() ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $defaults = array(
            'user_id'       => "",
            'follow_to'     => "",
            'username'      => "Default Username"
        );

        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

        // First you have to check if the user already exists and return his Following Row
        $following = array();
        $existing = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT following FROM {$this->table} WHERE user_id = %d", $args["user_id"] ) );

        if( ! empty( $existing ) ) {
            $following = json_decode( $existing );
        }

        // We check if this user ($args["user_id"]) is already following the $args["follow_to"] user.
        if( in_array( $args["follow_to"], $following ) )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            array_push( $following, $args['follow_to'] );
        }
        // We verify if the user exists and update the value, if he does not and we sent username, then, we create it.
        if( null === $existing && ! empty( $args['username'] ) ) {
            $wpdb->insert(
                $this->table,
                array(
                    'user_id' => $args['user_id'],
                    'username' => $args['username'],
                    'following' => json_encode( $following ),
                    'followers' => json_encode( array() )
                ),
                array(
                    '%d',
                    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s'
                )
            );

            return $wpdb->insert_id;
        } else {
            $updated = $wpdb->update(
                $this->table,
                array(
                    'following' => json_encode( $following )
                ),
                array( 
                    'user_id' => $args["user_id"]
                ),
                "%s",
                "%d"
            );

            return $updated;
        }
    }

    function add_followed_by( $args, $defaults ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $defaults = array(
            'user_id'       => "",
            'followed_by'   => "",
            'username'      => "Default Username"
        );

        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

        // First you have to check if the user already exists and return his Followers Row
        $followers = array();
        $existing = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT followers FROM {$this->table} WHERE user_id = %d", $args["user_id"] ) );

        if( ! empty( $existing ) ) {
            $followers = json_decode( $existing );
        }

        // We check if this user ($args["user_id"]) is already followed by $args["followed_by"] user.
        if( in_array( $args["followed_by"], $followers ) )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            array_push( $followers, $args['followed_by'] );
        }

        // We verify if the user exists and update the value, if he does not and we sent username, then, we create it.
        if( null === $existing && ! empty( $args['username'] ) ) {
            $wpdb->insert(
                $this->table,
                array(
                    'user_id' => $args['user_id'],
                    'username' => $args['username'],
                    'following' => json_encode( array() ),
                    'followers' => json_encode( $followers )
                ),
                array(
                    '%d',
                    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s'
                )
            );

            return $wpdb->insert_id;
        } else {
            $updated = $wpdb->update(
                $this->table,
                array(
                    'followers' => json_encode( $followers )
                ),
                array( 
                    'user_id' => $args["user_id"]
                ),
                "%s",
                "%d"
            );

            return $updated;
        }
    }
}

new TestThis();
```

I did tested it with this jQuery code:
* User to follow ID 2 should exists or we should send the username to add_followed_by function.

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, { 'action' : "add_follower", "user_to_follow" : 2 }, function() {
    console.log( "listo" );
}).fail(function(err) { console.log(err); })
```

Let me know if you have questions.

UPDATE: Code for unfollow.

```
if( ( $key = array_search( $args['unfollow_to'], $following ) ) !== false ) {
    unset( $following[$key] );
    reset( $following );

    $updated = $wpdb->update( $this->table,
        array(
            'following' => json_encode( $following )
        ),
        array( 
            'user_id' => $args['user_id']
        ), 
        '%s', '%d'
    );

    return $updated;

}
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you, with this approach, I am using **json_encode and json_decode of PHP**, instead of comma separated values.

Comment: Oddly, it's not working. I'll take a closer look at it tomorrow morning ;)  Is there a specific reason why `json_encode` and `json_decode` is prefered to be used? And also a big thank you in advance.

Comment: I prefer to use json_encode and json_decode in this one because we can register a full array inside a field as a string, even, **we can add a string value with a comma inside it too**. **It is more robust and flexible**. And when you are creating the comma separated string, you have to make sure not to add a comma at the end, because it will create an empty item inside your array, e.g., 23, 42, 53, <- This last comma is a very common error on comma separated string.

Comment: Got it! I noticed that the code it still not quite working as intended. The users are being added perfectly in the `db` but the values of the `followers` and `following` columns remains `0`. Do you perhaps have any idea?

Comment: Remains 0?  hehehe, I got it!, I am sorry I forgot to tell you, followers and following should be a **TEXT** field, not **bigint**, because it is a **String** that is going to be stored on it. What a json_encode and json_decode functions do is to convert you **String** to **Array** and **Array** to **String.**

Comment: Make sense and got it all working thanks to you!  I'll also be making an `unfollow` option and planning to reuse your code above and using it with `unset($array[$user_id]);` I'll keep you posted. :)

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, would you be willing to look at my unfollow code? I thought it was easy but the `unset( $following[$remove_id] );` isn't quite working. See post below.

Comment: Because I can not comment (I need more reputation), then, I updated your code, if you can't see the update, I will put it in my response as an update.

Answer (score 0):

The unfollow option is looking like this:

UPDATE:
This should work.

```
if( ( $key = array_search( $args['unfollow_to'], $following ) ) !== false ) {
    unset( $following[$key] );
    reset( $following );

    $updated = $wpdb->update( $this->table,
        array(
            'following' => json_encode( $following )
        ),
        array( 
            'user_id' => $args['user_id']
        ), 
        '%s', '%d'
    );

    return $updated;

}
```

It is because you were removing by the `key`, and it should be by the `value` instead.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I noticed something odd inside the database that's causing a conflict whenever I click on an unfollow button; the array turns into an object. Will update my first post about it. :)

Comment: I am sorry, I has been really busy this week, you can force the Object to Array conversion with  `json_encode( (array) $followers )` and  `json_encode( (array) $following )` in your `$wpdb->update`.

Comment: Thank you! That indeed solves the object error. Still I'm curious why inside the `following` column `quotes ("")` are listed and in the `followers` column there are none.

Comment: I noticed that other than using `(array)`,  `json_decode( $existing, true );` works slightly better. :)